# Apache As-Is Redirect is Internal... WHY?

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

So I have a pretty standard Apache 2 setup, with `AllowOverride all`.

And I have three files in the "testing" folder under my docroot:

*.htaccess*

```
AddHandler send-as-is .asis
```

*page.html*

```
this is the page!
```

*wtf.asis*

```
Status: 301 Copy Is Elsewhere
Location: /testing/page.html
Content-Type: text/plain

Redirecting...
```

When I point my browser at `/testing/wtf.asis`, I see the text "this is the page!", but the address bar still says `/testing/wtf.asis`.  I expected to see `/testing/page.html` in the address bar instead and to get a 301 redirect!  Instead, I get a 200 response.  What's going on?  Is it doing an internal redirect?  If so, why?

Comment: Found the answer (below), but does anyone know any more details as to why this happens?

Comment: I had a vague idea that `Location` needs a full URL. Looking through the Apache2 source at [`$TOP/modules/generators/mod_asis.c`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/generators/mod_asis.c?view=markup) I see no comment there as to why this behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I suspect that Location needs a full URL. Can you try that?

Comment: This works.  Sigh, Apache, why do you do this?

Comment: I looked a little but further, and it seems there is some CGI specification that tells web servers to make redirects without domain names internal.  Sounds nifty, but relying on it is another matter.

Comment: You inspired me to look at the RFC; section 6.2.2 of http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875 says your server will do an internal subrequest if you return a bare "Location: /full-path-without-http-host" without other headers. Graham Dumpleton (author of `mod_wsgi`) says Apache will also accept an `Status: 200` header. Perhaps you can try to return a Content-Type (for example) and see if the redirect is still handled as an internal subrequest?